# how to store embedded file (includes) in custom Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I created my own format in Rmarkdown based on this [blogpost](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_custom_formats.html). I implemented it in my personal package and it works great. I also added custom files in `includes` argument of `html_document`.

My question is whether it's possible to store my custom files (included in `includes` argument) after I click Knit button. Similarly to `self_contained = F` option which allows storing all Rmarkdown dependencies.

**Update**

I should give you some context first. Let’s say I used my `html` format to create a report two months ago. Two weeks later I decided to implement major changes in my `html` format and updated my package.

After next two weeks, my boss came to me asking for adding minor changes in old report. Then, by clicking `Knit` button, the report was not able to create, because there was a new version of my `html` format, which was significantly different.

I see three possibilities how to deal with this request. Either I can install old version of my package (suboptimal), create a new `html` format every time I implement major changes or I can **store my dependencies** (header, footer, css files) in a separate subdirectory (like a packrat). Then each report would be independent and immune to changes in my custom format.

Let me know if there is any better solution.

Comment: Are you open to embedding your includes as *base64*? It will add a fair amount of bloat to the document, but provided you ensure backwards compatibility with your package that is one way to ensure they render in future. Thinking through your solution design in your package to allow greater flexibility is most likely a more robust fix

Comment: Side thought: instead of trying to pack dependencies within the Rmd file, if your workflow included version control (e.g., git or subversion), you could go "back in time" to when the report was generated, branch (in order to make those tweaks), and then return to the master's "HEAD". Not an answer, sorry for the tangent.

Comment: @r2evans Obviously it's one way to solve it but only if I am the only person who use custom format. But when other people use it, it's hard to expect from them, to always remember about changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic example

Assume that you have a `myreport.Rmd` file with the following header:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Romain Lesur"
date: "27 janvier 2018"
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: inheader.html
---
```

Using a hacky `rmarkdown` preprocessor, you can copy `inheader.html` file.
The following code is intended to be run in `R` console:

```
pre_processor <- function(metadata, 
                          input_file, 
                          runtime, 
                          knit_meta, 
                          files_dir, 
                          output_dir) {

  in_header <- metadata$output$html_document$includes$in_header
  if (!is.null(in_header)) file.copy(in_header, output_dir)

  invisible(NULL)
}

custom_output_format <- function() {
  rmarkdown::output_format(
    knitr = NULL,
    pandoc = NULL,
    pre_processor = pre_processor,
    base_format = rmarkdown::html_document()
  )
}

rmarkdown::render('myreport.Rmd', 
                   output_format = custom_output_format(), 
                   output_dir = 'output')
```

You get a `output` directory with the rendered report and `inheader.html` file inside.

In order to run a similar preprocessor on clicking `Knit` button, you have to include it in your personal package's `output_format` (see below).

### Turning in a package

As the question mentions this [blogpost](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_custom_formats.html), here is an adaptation of the `quarterly_report` function:

```
quarterly_report <- function(toc = TRUE) {

  # get the locations of resource files located within the package
  css <- system.file("reports/styles.css", package = "mypackage")
  header <- system.file("reports/quarterly/header.html", package = "mypackage")

  # call the base html_document function
  base_format <-
    rmarkdown::html_document(toc = toc,
                             fig_width = 6.5,
                             fig_height = 4,
                             theme = NULL,
                             css = css,
                             includes = includes(before_body = header))

  pre_processor <- function(metadata,
                            input_file,
                            runtime,
                            knit_meta,
                            files_dir,
                            output_dir) {
    purrr::walk(c(css, header), file.copy, output_dir)

    invisible(NULL)
  }

  rmarkdown::output_format(
    knitr = NULL,
    pandoc = NULL,
    pre_processor = pre_processor,
    base_format = base_format
  )
}
```

This solution is not 100% satisfying because I don't think that `rmarkdown` `pre_processor` was created for having side-effects. But it works.